# Pandas dataframe with multiindex column - change levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, levels

source data：

[image]

```py
pd.pivot_table(ceshi, values=['num1', 'num2'], index=['date'],
            columns=['c'], aggfunc={'num1': np.sum,'num2': np.sum}, fill_value=0)
```

[image]

how to  transform to?：

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(ceshi, values=['num1', 'num2'], index=['date'],
                   columns=['c'], aggfunc={'num1': np.sum,'num2': np.sum}, fill_value=0)
```

And then:

```
df = df.swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```